# How to use NumberFormat in Java for custom currency formatting?

Tags: java, currency

I have this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "2300.99 EUR";
        String out = formatCurrency(in);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
    
    private static String formatCurrency(String txt) {
        String part[] = txt.split(" ", 2);
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(part[0]);
        
        return NumberFormat.getInstance().format(num);;
    }
}
```

This returns 2,300.99. However, I would like to have 2.300,99. How to do it? Locale is hr.

Comment: "Locale is hr", but you're not setting the locale anywhere...

Comment: Yes, and I used getCurrencyInstance which is with locale version. the result is the same .. hm maybe this is correct for my locale, but I would like it my way xxx.xxx,xx

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen, you had it right. I solved it with adding `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("hr"));`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an immediate solution for your code, but I highly recommend using the Java Money and Currency API (JSR-354) to solve your problem. It addresses the standardization of currencies and monetary amounts in Java. And of course, parsing and formatting are included.

Example showing different ways of formatting for different locales:

```java
    public static void main(final String... args) {

        final var amount = Money.of(123.456, "EUR");

        final var formatDE = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(Locale.GERMANY);
        System.out.println(formatDE.format(amount));

        final var formatCH = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(new Locale("de_CH"));
        System.out.println(formatCH.format(amount));

        final var formatUS = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(Locale.US);
        System.out.println(formatUS.format(amount));
    }
```

Comment: Hm, my case is strange. It could be any locale but I need it always 123.456,78

Comment: That looks like a format used e.g. in Germany. So you can always output formatted for Germany.